# Flake8 not giving errors/warnings on missing docstring or code not following PEP8 naming convention

Tags: python, lint, flake8

I am trying to run Flake8 for my python code however I'm noticing it's not giving me any of the PyDocStyle errors on a simple class with missing docstrings or warning about my class name `cars` which should be `Cars` according to [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Example code file (cars.py)

```
class cars:
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_value = some_value
```

when I run `flake8 cars.py` I get the following output:

```
cars.py:3:37: W292 no newline at end of file
```

I'm trying to configure Flake8 to run some common style checks but not finding any help in the [Flake8 documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/flake8/downloads/pdf/latest/) about how to enable [PyDocStyle](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/2.1.1/error_codes.html) error codes.

For comparison, I ran the same file against Pylint and here is the output

```
************* Module code.cars                                                                                                
cars.py:3:0: C0304: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)                                                             
cars.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)                                                       
cars.py:1:0: C0103: Class name "cars" doesnt conform to PascalCase naming style (invalid-name)                               
cars.py:1:0: C0115: Missing class docstring (missing-class-docstring)                                                         
cars.py:1:0: R0903: Too few public methods (0/2) (too-few-public-methods)                                                                                                                                                                                   
------------------------------------                                                                                          
Your code has been rated at -6.67/10
```

I'm using python 3.7.6, flake8 3.7.9 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.5.0, pyflakes: 2.1.1) CPython 3.7.6 on Linux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So what I found out was that by default Flake8 wraps `pycodestyle: 2.5.0` by default which from the documentation says:

> Among other things, these features are currently not in the scope of
>   the pycodestyle library:
>
> - naming conventions: this kind of feature is supported through plugins.
>     Install flake8 and the pep8-naming extension to use this feature.
> - docstring conventions: they are not in the scope of this library; see
>     the pydocstyle project.
> - automatic fixing: see the section PEP8 Fixers
>     in the related tools page.

So I installed `pep8-naming`, as well as `flake8-docstrings` and after running `flake8 --version` I got the below which shows it is now using the installed plugins:

```
3.7.9 (flake8-docstrings: 1.5.0, pydocstyle: 5.0.2, mccabe: 0.6.1, naming: 0.8.2, pycodestyle: 2.5.0, pyflakes: 2.1.1) CPython 3.7.6 on Darwin
```

I reran my check `flake8 cars.py` and I got the below output:

```
cars.py:1:1: D100 Missing docstring in public module
cars.py:2:1: D101 Missing docstring in public class
cars.py:2:8: N801 class name 'cars' should use CapWords convention
cars.py:3:1: D107 Missing docstring in __init__
```

At a first impression - after checking out the git repos for `flake8` and the additional plugins I had to install I am slightly skeptical on Flake8. The reason being is as at the time of writing Pylint seems to come packaged with the behavior I need as well as being around longer which benefits from stability and more contributors. Contrast to `flake8` which is newer, and to achieve the desired behavior it is necessary to install 3rd party plugins/libraries that might be abandoned in a year or two or break when `flake8` upgrades. Either scenario is problematic with the latter being troublesome if you're not careful with mentioning specific version/builds in CI pipelines.

Comment: genuinely curious what you possibly mean by "it's for the fanboys" (I'm the current maintainer) -- flake8 and its plugin ecosystem are some of the most depended on projects in the python ecosystem

Comment: Anthony - very nice of you to drop in here and leave a comment I appreciate it. I updated my comment about fanboys as it may be interpreted as having a negative connotation, I would have preferred to use the word "enthusiast". Just trying to bring up the point that as of today the `flake8` ecosystem is newer and relies on plugins to achieve common behavior found in Pylint. I feel this plugin ecosystem works only if the community support is there for plugin development.

Comment: when you say "newer" -- you realize both have been around for >10 years right?  pyflakes and pylint both appeared around mid-late 2004.  the reason you see fewer commits in `flake8` is because flake8 itself _does not implement checks_ but builds a strong foundation for a plugin ecosystem.  [historically](https://pepy.tech/project/flake8) flake8 has >25% more downloads than pylint.  I'm not saying pylint is bad/worse but your assessment seems quite short sighted :)

Comment: Anthony can't argue with the numbers you present there. I agree - I'll be exploring flake8 more before I jump to conclusions